# How can we do multiple process in php without using pcntl_fork()?

Tags: php, multithreading

How can we do multiple process in php without using **pcntl_fork()**?

I google many times but found nothing usefull. My server doesn't support **pcntl_fork()**.

Comment: Yes I can. Thanks for answer my question:)

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, please tell me how can **exec()** work?

Comment: What about reading the documentation? `http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have php cli available you can use exec() or system() to fork processes. But sometimes a more elegant way is to make http subrequests in background and use the original url target only as controlling instance.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I did it someway. But it don't make process faster. Sory if I forget any thing.

Comment: Do you want to express that you want to use multiple processes to increase performance/get a faster execution? If so, please edit your question above and say so!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that simple way to do that is use **exec()**. @arkascha thank you so much!

Now we can do multiple process in php and use exit() to return whatever we want from these processes.